# Is it possible to place the values of a mail merge datasource into an array variable?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA. I apologize for any inconvenience caused by this question.

I'm trying to place the values of the data source into a variable array. These are my codes for reference.

```
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim FilePath As String

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
        If .Display Then
            If .Name <> "" Then
                FilePath = .Name

                With ActiveDocument.MailMerge

                Dim tempVariable() As String
                'To attach selected file to the data source

                '**ERROR**
                tempVariable = Array(
                ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=FilePath, _
                                        ReadOnly:=True, _
                                        LinkToSource:=True, _
                                        SubType:=WdMergeSubType.wdMergeSubTypeOther)

'                ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=FilePath, _
'                                        ReadOnly:=True, _
'                                        LinkToSource:=True, _
'                                        SubType:=WdMergeSubType.wdMergeSubTypeOther
                End With
            End If '.Name <> "" Then
        Else '.Display Then
            MsgBox "No file selected", vbOKOnly, "File not selected"
        End If '.Display Then
    End With
```

Unfortunately though, there will be an error that says...

> Compile error:   Expected: end of statement

What can I do to solve this issue? From what I have assumed, it's a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what end are you trying to place the data into an array? It's not going to help complete a mailmerge. That said, try:

```
Sub Capture_Merge_Data()
Dim d As Long, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
  d = .DataFields.Count: r = .RecordCount
  ReDim DataArray(d, r)
  For i = 1 To r
    .ActiveRecord = i
    For j = 1 To d
      DataArray(j - 1, i - 1) = .DataFields(j)
      If i * j Mod 1000 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Next j
  Next i
End With
MsgBox "DataArray populated with " & d & " data fields from " & r & " records."
End Sub
```

Comment: Was trying to grab the data for display which you have answered perfectly.

Thank you!